# Search in current column of DataGridView using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I want to search in selected column (current column) an showing result in DataGridView, but when search a value don't show anything in DataGridView
Check my code :

```
private void txt_search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int columnIndx = dgv_prs_add.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    string columnName = dgv_prs_add.Columns[columnIndx].Name;
    lblPath.Text = columnIndx.ToString() + columnName.ToString();
    var query = (from d in db.tbl_PrsInfos
            where txt_search.Text.Contains(columnName)
            select d).ToList();
    dgv_prs_add.DataSource = query;
}
```

Comment: Check your code for?

Comment: Why not use query instead.  The row number and column numbers are the same in the query as the DGV.

Comment: @EpicKip Oh yes, you're right. I've edited

Comment: You are searching for columnName in the text which I doubt is what you expect. What you need to do is create the search criteria at run time based on the selected column and then pass it to the Where LINQ method of you table.

Comment: @jdweng if it's possible for you, elaborate more to me via coding. thanks

Comment: Something like this : var results = query.AsEnumerable().Select((x,i) => new { value = x.Field<string>("Column Name"), row = i}).Where(x => x.value == "abc").ToList();  If columns are numbers or dates you will have to change <string> to database type.

Answer (score 1):

You should create criteria to filter the records at run time based on the selected column.

You can use `Where` LINQ method to apply criteria on the table. This method takes criteria in the form of `Func<T, bool>` and applies to the list at run time.

```
private void txt_search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int columnIndx = dgv_prs_add.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    string columnName = dgv_prs_add.Columns[columnIndx].Name;
    lblPath.Text = columnIndx.ToString() + columnName.ToString();

    //Assuming that class name is "PersonInfo".
    Func<PersonInfo, bool> criteria;

    var searchString = txt_search.Text;
    //Assuming that columns are "FirstName", "LastName" and "Address".
    switch (columnName)
    {
        case "FirstName":
            criteria = person=> person.FirstName.Contains(searchString);
            break;
        case "LastName":
            criteria = person=> person.LastName.Contains(searchString);
            break;
        case "Address":
            criteria = person=> person.Address.Contains(searchString);
            break;
        default:
            criteria = person=> true;
            break;
    }

    var query = db.tbl_PrsInfos.Where(criteria).ToList();

    dgv_prs_add.DataSource = query;
}
```

As mentioned in the code, I have assumed some of the things such as ClassName and its properties. You need to put appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks for answer me, it get me error in line _**criteria = person => person.FirstName.Contains(searchString);**_ . Error : _does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no extension method 'FirstName' accepting a first argument of type_

Comment: I mentioned in the answer that you need to use appropriate property and class names. Don't just copy paste the code. You need to put proprety names of your class and columnames of your table...

Comment: Yes i do it, but gives me the error again, my class name is "Personal_Info" and column names is "FullName","Personely" and "Email".

Comment: I solved this but now gives me new error : Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Func<BMS.Personal_Info,bool>' D:\C# Projects\BMS - Copy\BMS\Personal_Info.cs 243 32 BMS